# Angular: what is the best way to run code on the next tick?

Tags: angular

I'm writing on blur handler for input (mat-input), which manipulates DOM if a form become valid. I want to be sure that validation errors are disappeared for this moment, that's why I wrap my code in `setTimeout` to run it on the next tick?

Is there a good Angular way to run some code on the next tick?

Comment: well since we can't see your code, I'm not sure what your best option would be. But I generally use `setTimeout` for code to run on the next digest cycle.

Comment: Thanks @rhavelka, my question is rather general than specific to the current code. I guess, there you be something like `ngZone.runNext` or some use case for schedulers. Of course, we can simply make it async using setTimeout / Promise / RxJs - for me it looks like a workaround though.

Answer (score -1):

> Example of a input that shows and hides error message on blur [Stack Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/material-form-validation-fjqow5)

**Question**: Is there a good Angular way to run some code on the next tick?

**Answer**: Yes! Use Angular form controls to manage the form state. Angular updates automagically.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {

  input = new FormControl('', {
    validators: [Validators.required, Validators.minLength(3)],
    updateOn: 'blur'
  });

  getErrorMessage() {
    return this.input.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' :
      this.input.hasError('minlength') ? 'Minimum length is 3 characters' :
        '';
  }
}



<mat-card class="searchbox">
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput  placeholder="Enter three of more characters" [formControl]="input" required>
    <mat-error *ngIf="input.invalid">{{getErrorMessage()}}</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
<button mat-stroked-button>GO</button>
```

Comment: This answers for a specific use case, and is not generic enough to be used anywhere else.